# Failed to parse HTTP tbody element using requests

Tags: python, https, html-parsing, python-requests

I am trying to parse https://courses.illinois.edu/schedule/2016/spring/CS/125 this website and get the table element from it.
I used requests in python

```
r = requests.get(url)
print r.text
```

and I cannot get the contend in tbody which exists

```
<tbody></tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you view the source in your web browser you will notice there is no text in the `<tbody>` tags.  If you search for the text that you are looking for you will find it in the `<script type="text/javascript">` tags.  Unfortunately requests does not handle javascript so you will have to find another tool to get that information.